# Vagrant Errors after Windows 8.1 update

Tags: windows, virtualbox, vagrant, puppet, windows-8.1

After a recent update of my OS from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 my vagrant setup has stopped working.

I try running vagrant up on boxes and I get the following:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...

The guest machine entered an invalid state while waiting for it to boot Valid states are   'starting, running'. The machine is in the 'poweroff' state. Please verify everything is configured properly and try again.
```

I've tried updating vagrant. I've updated VirtualBox to 4.3. I've tried specifically setting VirtualBox to run as Administrator and in compatibility mode for Windows 8. That didn't work. Also tried compatibility mode for Windows 7. No dice.

Anyone else having these problems? Windows 8.1 is to new to find reports of this through Google searching. hopefully someone here can help out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, here is how I actually managed to fix it.

The newest versions of Vagrant (1.3.5) and VirtualBox (4.3.4) do not play together at all on Windows. So, I kept Vagrant 1.3.5 and went down to VirtualBox 4.2.2.

Once you have that, you have to get rid of a couple folders so that everything resets itself correctly:

```
Users\<<USERNAME>>\.VirtualBox
Users\<<USERNAME>>\.vagrant.d
```

Delete those before trying to run

```
vagrant up
```

With that, I was able to get everything running again. However, I have noticed that running vagrant up does go a tad slower than it had been previously. I can live with that though.

Thank you for all of your help and suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem and figured out the problem. Turns out I did not have the proper virtualization settings enabled in my bios.

Vagrant emitted a helpful error:

> If the provider you're using has a GUI that comes with it, it is often
>   helpful to open that and watch the machine, since the GUI often has
>   more helpful error messages than Vagrant can retrieve.
>
> For example, if you're using VirtualBox, run `vagrant up` while the
>   VirtualBox GUI is open.

Followed the instructions and tried to power on the vm via the GUI and was greeted with this error:

[image: Virtual box error]

Was able to `vagrant up` after turning on the proper settings in my bios.

OS: Windows 8.1, Vagrant version: 1.3.5, Virtual Box version: 4.3.4

Answer (score 0):

opening VirtualBox GUI may give you a better idea of what's going on. 4.3 has been recently released, so if you've updated, your issue may be related to that

Comment: I had been running 4.2.16. Same problem. Upgraded to 4.2.18. Same problem. 

4.2.16 was always working fine. A colleague of mine had been using 4.2.18 and it was working fine as well. So now I fear that my problem is universal, but we may run into a new issue with 4.3 once this problem is resolved. Fun times.

Answer (score 0):

Running Vagrant on Windows 8.1 has caused Windows 8.1 to reboot shortly after a vagrant up for me.  I am able to recreate this every time.